# Do the Riddler interrogations ever end?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In *Batman: Arkham City*, you eventually acquire the ability to spot informants for Riddler trophies (they're highlighted in green while in detective mode). I've noticed that these informants keep popping up in the same spots after interrogating them earlier.

Do they always show in similar spots, and do they stop spawning at some point after you've gotten all the information about an area out of them? Or will they just keep spawning? I've only probably located (not gathered) about 75% of the Riddler trophies on the map at this point.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that after you've collected every last riddler trophy they'd quit spawning...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They will stop spawning after you get all the remaining challenges on your map. Basically, Batman stops <del>beating them for information</del> interrogating them when he has all the remaining locations.

Comment: Do you really get the location for *all* the riddles? For me there was a single riddle for which the location was never revealed.

Comment: @BruceConnor It seemed to me that I got the locations for all the remaining unsolved riddles I had.

Answer (score 16):

The Riddler trophy information isn't tied to specific thugs; if you accidentally knock one out, you haven't 'missed' him. Which thugs are the Riddler informants are based on spawn patterns, and when interrogated they'll give you the locations of five Riddler challenges you haven't yet recorded, as close as possible to the area you're in. As you mop them up you'll start to receive information about riddles and Joker balloons, and then about locations outside the area you're in. (Riddler informants, as far as I can tell, will never tell you the locations of cameras, but there's another way to get that information late in the game.)

Comment: +1 for more detail - that they give you 5 locations, as well as moving onto riddles, balloons, etc. did not know that!